# System.Byte[] on Datagridview

Tags: c#, oracle, winforms

I am getting data from oracle database to datagridview.

The column type in Oracle is = `RAW(8 BYTE)`

However when i bind this to datagrid it doesn't show the values. It just shows `System.Byte[]` in all rows for that column.

Example real value is = `000000006F478320`

Also i found the data type mapping however i didn't undestand that how should i use it ;

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/oracle-data-type-mappings

How can i show all real values instead of `System.Byte[]` ?

Comment: Whats suppose to be inside this column? what kind of data, since byte can be anything, anyhow it's clear you need to parse this before you can use it, you just need to know what to parse it to.

Comment: Can you please show how the information is being associated with the column? You should find it in the designer file.

Comment: @Zorkind i already said that the real value is '000000006F478320'

Comment: well that looks like "something" to me, what those bytes represent?

Comment: looks like hexa, is it some sort of key?

Comment: @LordWilmore didn't understand it. i just 'select * from table' and data comes.

Comment: @Zorkind I don't know this is oracle table and table has column type 'RAW'.